# How to get the matching records from SQL Server which are not connected by foreign key

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 2 dimension tables DimLegalEntity and DimMember. They are not connected with any foreign key. Both the tables has "name" column which contains name of the institution. I would like to get the result which contains matching name column from both the tables.

PS. Some data may contain abbreviation in DimLegalEntity.

Comment: You don't need foreign keys for fetching data. They are there just for referential integrity when inserting / deleting / updating rows. Having abbreviations is a problem anyhow. How big, that depends on your data & needs.

Comment: Not much. There are only few abbreviations. I can ignore that for now.

Answer (score 0):

you can inner join both the table , for join u  dont need primary foreign key relationship , as long as column value involved in join condition can be converted to one data type

Comment: Can you please provide the query?

Comment: could you share some sample data

Comment: Legal Entity Name
  TULLETT PREBON AMERICAS CORP.
AMER GEN FIN CORP/COMMOLOCO,INC.
PIPER JAFFRAY & CO.
MERRILL LYNCH PIERCE FENNER &SMITH
JP MORGAN CHASE & CO.(CP&TBA)

Comment: Same data is there in DimMember as well

Comment: are legal entity name remains same in both table ?

Comment: Yes. It is same

Comment: is thr any problem writing query like this ,select a.company from a join b on a.company = b.company , am i wrong somewhere getting your qn.? did i get u correctly!